# jQuery script not working with pre populated Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I hope I am not repeating an existing question, I have tried really hard to find what I need on the site, but now feel I need to ask the question, so here goes, I hope you guys can help me out :s

I have an array;

```
var 1Results = somecontent;
var 2Results = somecontent;
var 3Results = somecontent;
var 4Results = somecontent;

var nomResults = 1Results + 2Results + 3Results + 4Results;
```

I have a script that is supposed to weed out the duplicate numbers and display them (in **sorted_arr**);

```
    var arr = nomResults;
    var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
                                 // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
            results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

This script doesn't work, however is I change the script to this;

```
    var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
    var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
                                 // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
            results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

It works fine, any ideas why **.sort()** won't work with my pre popluated array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var nomResults = 1Results + 2Results + 3Results + 4Results;` is not an array and 1Results is not a valid JavaScript identifier. It should not even parse. Did you mean to use `var nomResults = [Results1,Results2,...]`?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the code to reflect additional arrays

Comment: Code is still showing that `nomResults` is just a concatenation of the other variables. It's still not an array. It is just a single value, so there is nothing to "sort." Your `var arr` IS an array (multiple comma-separated values inside square brackets), so it can sort.

Comment: In JavaScript identifier, the first character must be a letter, an underscore (_), or a dollar sign ($). It cannot be a digit.

'+' operator cannot be used to manipulate or create arrays. This is array: `[1,2,3]`; this is not an array, it's a 6: `1+2+3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use brackets notation to add elements to your new Array like :

```
var arr = [Results1, Results2...];
```

Or `Array.prototype.push()` :

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(Results1);
arr.push(Results2);
//...
```

Plus you can use a specific function for sorting, either declaring a new function compare :

```
function compare(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

Which will use actual values of your array (and not Strings, as specified in your comments).
Then you pass it to sort :

```
arr = arr.sort(compare);
```

Or directly use anonymous function, if you don't need it more than one time :

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I can see in your code.

1. The variable names must not begin with a number
2. var nomResults is not an array but a string

The below code works for me just fine-

`var results1 = "this", 
    results2="is", 
    results3="an", 
    results4="array",
    theArray = [results1, results2, results3, results4];`

`console.log(theArray);`

["this", "is", "an", "array"]

`console.log(theArray.sort());`

["an", "array", "is", "this"]

Answer (score 0):

I was building my array wrong!!! Thanks guys, I knew it would be something simple :)

Instead of this;

```
var nomResults = 1Results + 2Results + 3Results + 4Results;
```

I needed to do this;

```
var nomResults = [Results1, Results2, Results3, Results4];
```

I've been looking at this for so long, I didn't see it. My script is all working now and great, errors are all gone, this is amazing. Many props and thanks to @jpreynat Thank you SO much :) I need a holiday....